# Why are two people allowed to open the edit page at the same time?

Tags: support, edits

I edited a question and went to submit it when I was presented with this warning, is there a reason the other person was still allowed to open the edit page even though I was editing it?

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

I'm not asking why my edit got rejected or why edits aren't being merged, I just want to know if there's a reason two people are allowed to open the edit window at the same time and the second blocked from opening it.

Comment: How would you detect between a slow editor and one who forgot the tab was open and one who edits in an external editor?

Comment: If a edit tab has been open then no one else should be able to open an edit unless they timeout, that's what I would expect. Something like a 5 minute timer, if they don't answer it in that time show a message saying are you still editing, etc. if they don't respond then mark them as away and let the other person edit.

Comment: The server cannot know that you are editing (still, or even at all; perhaps you only wanted to have a look at the Markdown source). With the measures you propose, a malicious user could prevent others from editing a post basically forever.

Comment: The server can? That's what ajax, etc are for. Considering what this site is for I would expect something like this to have already been considered.

Comment: So if you keep hitting the timer at 4:59 you can lock out other editors indefinitely?

Comment: Obviously there would be some conditions on it, like for example checking if the edit box is being typed in like Facebook, etc. does with the `is typing` message. It's just annoying editing a post to make it readable, going to submit it and then finding someone edited the question to just change a single word.

Comment: Not all browsers support heavy JS.