# Why even let me edit when another edit is awaiting approval for a post?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

I was going through some questions and one of them looked nasty and not properly formatted. I decided to edit it and clicked the `edit` button. The edit page loaded and I did a lot of work there — fixing the spacing, quoting errors, putting code into code samples, etc. And when I finish and click `save edit` I get this error:

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

I understand that this is important, but why even let me edit it in the first place and waste my time? As soon as an edit was submitted for review and as a result my edit wont be accepted for the moment until the pending edit is reviewed, shouldn't I be stopped there or at least be warned?

That really wasted a my time as someone else probably has made an as good edit and my edit is useless now. This is not a duplicate of *[Why are two people allowed to open the edit page at the same time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266398/why-are-two-people-allowed-to-open-the-edit-page-at-the-same-time)*
or
*[Why there is no Syncing Mechanism for Editing posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172020/why-there-is-no-syncing-mechanism-for-editing-posts)*, but it is very similar to *[Lock a post for editing, or at least display a warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/lock-a-post-for-editing-or-at-least-display-a-warning)*
which in addition to it I want to suggest a preview of the edit the other user has made and whether I want to continue or not after knowing that he/she has submitted an edit for review and the review that I am about to submit is simply going to be rejected.

**Update**: Now that another user submitted a review and it got accepted the page says "This post has been edited 2 times since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit", which is really good. Although could be better if one could see this kind of warnings when the review was submitted, as I proposed earlier.

**Further explanation from comment**:

And exactly to my point I proposed to show a message that a new edit request has been submitted so that I can stop at that moment and waste no more time. Additionally, promoting the user to continue edit anyway if he/she thinks his/her edit is better than the one that was submitted right then. (Of course SO could restrict this feature to some high rep guys.)

Comment: First of all, your first two references are duplicates of the third. Second, your additional request makes no sense. "Do you want to continue, knowing that your edit will just be rejected anyway?" Who would ever answer yes to that? As far as I can tell, this really is a duplicate of the third reference. If not, what else are you asking for that's different?

Comment: I suspect that when you clicked ´edit’, the other edit wasnt started, when you clicked save, now the script seen another edit done. a edit ninja

Comment: @Jason Bassford One can not be sure if the edit will definitely be rejected. What if my edit is better than the user currently editing it. So one can choose to go on and further improve the quality of the question.

Comment: @yagmoth55 Yes that's exactly what is happening. And exactly to my point I proposed to show a message that a new edit request has been submitted so that I can stop at that moment and waste no more time. Additionally promoting the user to continue edit anyways if he thinks his edit is better than the one that was submitted right then. (Of course SO could restrict this feature to some high rep guys)

Comment: @Jason And if you read the third paragraph of my question again you will find out what different I am proposing. Thanks.